# How to center a text generated from an API in JS?

Tags: javascript, text, bootstrap-5, api-design

I'm learning how to generate content with API's, but when I print in screen the generated text does not alignt with the rest of the container.

The issue is that I need the card to be centered in the screen with all text centered but the generated text only is shown at the left of the card.

```js
const jokeText = document.querySelector(".joke");

async function buscarChiste() {
  const response = await fetch("https://icanhazdadjoke.com", {
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
    },
  });

  const joke = response.json();
  return joke;
}

async function pulsarBoton() {
  const {
    joke
  } = await buscarChiste();
  jokeText.innerText = joke;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body class="container bg">
  <div class="card row border-primary text-center" style="width: 40rem;">
    <img src="../img/meme.jpg" class="card-img-top mx" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Best dad jokes!</h5>
      <div class="col-6 joke text-center"></div>
      <button class="col-6 btn btn-primary" onclick="pulsarBoton()">Pulsa para un nuevo chiste</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="api.js"></script>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance!

Centering the API generated text

Answer (score 0):

The text is centered but you have `col-6` on the `div`, so the container is taking 50% width of the available space making it look like it's left-aligned. Either remove `col-6` or use a breakpoint: [More](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/columns/).

```js
const jokeText = document.querySelector(".joke");

async function buscarChiste() {
  const response = await fetch("https://icanhazdadjoke.com", {
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
    },
  });

  const joke = response.json();
  return joke;
}

async function pulsarBoton() {
  const {
    joke
  } = await buscarChiste();
  jokeText.innerText = joke;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body class="container bg">
  <div class="card row border-primary text-center" style="width: 40rem;">
    <img src="../img/meme.jpg" class="card-img-top mx" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Best dad jokes!</h5>
      <div class="joke text-center"></div>
      <button class="col-6 btn btn-primary" onclick="pulsarBoton()">Pulsa para un nuevo chiste</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="api.js"></script>
</body>
```